# How do I use the return values from csv ajax request for x and y values?

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, chart.js

I am trying to import a csv file and use it as the data source for my scatter chart in ChartJs. When I print dataPoints I get object arrays of the correct value so I know the ajax request is pulling properly. But I cant seem to pass these values into my datasets data as x and y values.

I was able to successfully pull the data and plug it into x and y values using canvasJS unfortunately that framework isn't free so I am trying to switch to chart.js. Ive tried plugging in data: [{dataPoints: pullData()}] or data: pullData() or data: [dataPoints] and plenty of other combinations but none seem to work. I am familiar with coding in swift and java but I'm particularly new to Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const CHART = document.getElementById("scatterChart");
console.log(CHART);
var scatterChart = new Chart(CHART, {
type: 'scatter',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
        data: [{
            x: -10,
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: 0,
            y: 10
        }, {
            x: 10,
            y: 5
        }],
        borderColor: 'black',
         borderWidth: 1,
         pointBackgroundColor: '#00bcd6',
         pointRadius: 5,
         pointHoverRadius: 5,
         fill: false,
         tension: 0.5,
         showLine: true
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom'
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left'
        }]
    }
}
});

window.onload = function(){
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "mockData.csv",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function (result){
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(result);
    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        dataPoints.push({ 
                    x: data[i][0], 
                    y: data[i][1]
        });
        console.log(dataPoints)
    return dataPoints
   }
})
};
```

My goal is to plot the points from the csv (which is just 5 rows and 2 columns of basic numbers) but instead no points show up. Where as when I hand jam the values into x and y everything shows up fine.

Comment: Well, at minimum you need to move the creation of the chart to inside the success function of the ajax call, or of course pass dataPoints into some other function that creates the chart.

Comment: Okay I have copy and pasted all the code above the window.onload line into the success fuction right before the for loop begins. Where should I go from here? Should I make the for loop its own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the creation of the chart to inside the success function of the ajax call, or pass dataPoints into some other function that creates the chart.

Answer (score 0):

After @terpinmd suggestion I was able to resolve the problem. Below is the code solution:

```
function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv) {

    var dataPoints = csvLines = points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++)
        dataPoints.push({ 
                    x: csv[i][0], 
                    y: csv[i][1]
        });
        console.log(dataPoints)
    return dataPoints
 }

 window.onload = function(){
var dataPoints = [];
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "mockData.csv",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function (result){
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(result);

    const CHART = document.getElementById("scatterChart");
    console.log(CHART);
    var scatterChart = new Chart(CHART, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                data: getDataPointsFromCSV(data),
                borderColor: 'black',
                 borderWidth: 1,
                 pointBackgroundColor: '#00bcd6',
                 pointRadius: 5,
                 pointHoverRadius: 5,
                 fill: false,
                 tension: 0.5,
                 showLine: true
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left'
                }]
            }
        }
    });
   }
})
```

};